# Float a div right, without impacting on design

Tags: css, html, css-float

I want to float a div to the right at the top of my page. It contains a 50px square image, but currently it impacts on the layout of the top 50px on the page.

Currently its:

```
<div style="float: right;">
  ...
</div>
```

I tried z-index as I thought that would be the answer, but I couldn't get it going.

I know it's something simple I'm missing, but I just can't seem to nail it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

What do you mean by impacts? Content will flow around a float. That's how they work.

If you want it to appear above your design, try setting:

```
z-index: 10;  
position: absolute;  
right: 0;  
top: 0;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want the image to affect the layout at all (and float on top of other content) you can apply the following CSS to the image:

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
```

If you want it to float at the right of a particular parent section, you can add `position: relative` to that section.

Comment: There is no need to specify a unit when the value is zero. "right: 0;" works just the same as "right: 0pt;" or "right: 0px;".

Comment: Cheers — the perils of pasting from firebug!

Comment: @OlaTuvesson: Not needed does not mean we should not use it. I tend to always put the unit, so when I increase the number, I don't have to remember to add the unit.

Comment: @Danosaure: Holy thread resurrection Batman! :) You're right of course, if it helps keep track of things and does no harm (other than the extra TWO whole bytes in file size) then there's little wrong with it. Seeing it will still upset my sense of balance in the universe though. I mean zero is zero, it has no unit, colour or smell - it's just... nothing.

Comment: A bonus trick which I often use with `position: absolute;` is that an element with no values given for top/left/bottom/right will be positioned absolutely in the same spot it would have appeared with `position: static;` (the default). This makes it trivial to stack elements of equal size on top of each other. Another handy trick is that you can force an element to fill a parent element of unknown size (like, say, the <body>) by setting `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 100%; right: 100%;` Great for when you want to keep some padding on a stretchy container!

Comment: @OlaTuvesson Zero is also infinite possibilities. Zero is the total energy in the universe and the creator of the universe (Zero-point Energy).

Comment: @DanBray Ummm... No.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting its `position` to absolute. That takes it out of the flow of the document.